# How do I set a webjob to run every 1 hour in Azure

Tags: azure

I have a webjob running in Azure, it seems to work - but...

How can I make it run every 10 mins?

its a simple console app, published via Visual Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1: Scheduling Azure WebJobs using cron expressions

[image: cron expression field]

Azure WebJobs support scheduling using cron expressions for **Triggered** WebJobs with the Triggers set to **Scheduled**.

An example of a cron expression that runs every 10 minutes would be

```
0 */10 * * * *
```

See the [Azure function reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions) to see more examples of supported cron expressions.

**Note:** To use this way of scheduling WebJobs you'll have to configure the website as Always On (just as you would with continuous WebJobs)

### Method 2: Adding a schedule in Visual Studio

WebJobs can use a settings.job file to determine when a WebJob is run. Use this file to set an execution schedule for your WebJob.

**Example settings.json**

```
{
    "schedule": "0 */10 * * * *"
}
```

This file must be located at the root of the WebJobs folder, along side your WebJob's script, such as

```
wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous\{job name}
```

**Important:** Mark your settings.job file properties as **Copy if newer**.

### More Info

For more information about these two methods see:

[Scheduling Azure WebJobs with cron expressions](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/#.XmZ0GchKiUk) (blog.amitapple.com)

[Create a scheduled WebJob](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON) (docs.microsoft.com)